# Unhandled Network Error 401 When using Apollo in react native & empty graphql response

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

I am building a react-native app using `create-react-native-app` cli 
Here are the packages I am using. All of the latest stable except fiber

  `"dependencies": {
    "apollo-cache-inmemory": "^1.0.0",
    "apollo-client": "^2.0.1",
    "apollo-link": "^1.0.0",
    "apollo-link-error": "^1.0.0",
    "apollo-link-http": "^1.0.0",
    "expo": "^21.0.0",
    "graphql": "^0.11.7",
    "graphql-tag": "^2.5.0",
    "react": "16.0.0-alpha.12",
    "react-apollo": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native": "^0.48.4",
    "react-navigation": "^1.0.0-beta.15"
  }`

The app runs and routing navigation works fine. I have two routes, App and   FeedList.

the app talks to github graph api( I dont know if github access token is **required**, if so, i haved added it but I don't know if that's the correct way)

`Feedlist` is wrapped in a `graphql HoC` component and its props has a `data` which is already populated with results of the `graphql request`(even if the request fails)

You can refer to [The structure of the data prop](http://dev.apollodata.com/react/queries.html#default-result-props)

---

### App Component

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import ApolloClient from 'apollo-client'
import { ApolloLink } from 'apollo-link'
import { createHttpLink } from 'apollo-link-http'
import { InMemoryCache } from 'apollo-cache-inmemory'
import { ApolloProvider } from 'react-apollo';
import { onError } from 'apollo-link-error';
import Router from './router'

class App extends Component {
  createClient() {
    const httpLink = createHttpLink({ uri: 'https://api.github.com/graphql'})

    // handle network error
    const errorLink = onError(({ networkError }) => {
        if (networkError.statusCode === 401) {
          console.log(networkError)
        }
      // let errorMessage = networkError.statusCode === 401 ? 'Network error 104, handled' : 'link sucess'
      // console.log(errorMessage, networkError)
    })

    // apply widdleware to add access token to request
    let middlewareLink =  new ApolloLink((operation, forward) => {
      operation.setContext({
        headers: {
          authorization: 'GITHUB_ACCESS_TOKEN'
        }
      })
      return forward(operation)
    })
    const link = middlewareLink.concat(httpLink)
    

    // Initialize Apollo Client with URL to our server
    return new ApolloClient({
    link: link,
    cache: new InMemoryCache(),
    })
  }
  render () {
    return (
      <ApolloProvider client={this.createClient()}>
        <Router />
      </ApolloProvider>
    )
  }
}

export default App
```

---

### FeedList Component

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text } from 'react-native';
import { graphql } from 'react-apollo';
import gql from 'graphql-tag';

// The data prop, which is provided by the wrapper below contains,
// a `loading` key while the query is in flight and posts when ready
const FeedList = ({ data }) => {
  console.log(data) // returns default from HoC injected props
  console.log('FeedList Eroor!!',data.error) // returns undefined
  return data.error ? <Text> Error Fetching posts</Text>:<Text>fetching posts... </Text>
}

// The `graphql` wrapper executes a GraphQL query and makes the results
// available on the `data` prop of the wrapped component (PostList here)
export default graphql(gql`{
  search(type: REPOSITORY, query: "react", first: 20) {
    edges {
      node {
        ... on Repository {
          nameWithOwner
          owner {
            login
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}`, { options: { notifyOnNetworkStatusChange: true } })(FetchPost);
```

The important parts are the the Wrapped FeedList component which does log the data from props and the `createClient()` method inside App component.
I followed [this](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/blob/master/Upgrade.md#upgrading-from-custom-networkinteface-with-middleware--afterware) to try and catch the error that may happen during the data request.

The HoC wrapper component does its job and `FeedList`'s data prop has has everything but the response from the api.

[image: browser debug]

**Note that the error does not crash app**

[image: expo android debugger]

The above image shows also the same error message as on the `expo simulator on android`

So I guess the question i have is

1. How do I catch the error? [Here is a similar issue](https://github.com/apollographql/react-apollo/issues/604)
2. If its the way I structured my query thats the problem. How do I  correctly get the github api to return data correctl?

[Here is the repo you can run and reproduce the error](https://github.com/bnovf/react-native-github-graphql-app)

Note that [Issue#1](https://github.com/bnovf/react-native-github-graphql-app/issues/2) in that repo is similar to this SO question and [I have already fixed it by handling data.error as per the documentation](http://dev.apollodata.com/react/api-queries.html#graphql-query-data-error)

Also note that most of the documentation is for the older versions of `apollo-client` > v2.x.x

[Issue #2](https://github.com/bnovf/react-native-github-graphql-app/issues/2) is exactly what I am asking here. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A 401 status means invalid authentication. As you've guessed, you need a valid OAuth token to send with your request. For development purposes, you can just [generate one](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-a-personal-access-token-for-the-command-line/). Make sure you include the scopes outlines as outlined [here](https://developer.github.com/v4/guides/forming-calls/#authenticating-with-graphql):

```
user
public_repo
repo
repo_deployment
repo:status
read:repo_hook
read:org
read:public_key
read:gpg_key
```

You don't want users accessing the API through your credentials, so eventually you'll need to implement an OAuth2 authentication flow in your app to generate a token for each end user.

Comment: Thanks, changing   ```authorization: 'GITHUB_ACCESS_TOKEN'```

to  ```authorization : `Bearer ${GITHUB_ACCESS_TOKEN}``` helped me get rid of the error.

ofcourse that variable refering to the token I generated.

Plus I missed the 'Bearer' keyword. I am marking yours as answer. Cheers